# change frame tkinter dynamically

Tags: python, tkinter

I am designing a python game that requires a table, depending on the level the table must be 3x3, 4x4, or 5x5,
Is there a WAY to change the frame size where I have the table dynamically?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *

size_of_board = IntVar
N = IntVar
symbol_X_color = '#EE4035'
symbol_O_color = '#0492CF'
Green_color = '#7BC043'


class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        global size_of_board
        size_of_board = 600

        def setLevelEasy():
            global N
            N = 2

        def setLevelMedium():
            global N, size_of_board
            N = 3
            size_of_board = 1
            self.initialize_board()

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
        self.root.title("Game")
        self.root.configure(background='Teal')

        # MENU BAR
        my_menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=my_menu)
        level_menu = Menu(my_menu, font=('Helvetica', 20, 'bold'))
        my_menu.add_cascade(label="Level", menu=level_menu)
        level_menu.add_command(label='Easy: 3x3', command=setLevelEasy)
        level_menu.add_command(label='Medium: 4x4', command=setLevelMedium)
        level_menu.add_command(label='Hard: 5x5')
        level_menu.add_command(label='Very Hard: 6x6')

        self.initialize_board()

        # TITLE
        Tops = Frame(self.root, bg='Teal', pady=2, width=1350, height=100, relief=RIDGE)
        Tops.grid(row=0, column=0)

        lblTitle = Label(Tops, font=('arial', 30, 'bold'), text="Game", bd=21, bg='Teal', fg='Cornsilk',
                         justify=CENTER)
        lblTitle.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def initialize_board(self):
        global size_of_board
        print(size_of_board)

        MainFrame = Frame(self.root, bg='Turquoise', bd=10, width=size_of_board, height=size_of_board, relief=RIDGE)
        MainFrame.grid(row=1, column=0)


game_instance = Game()
game_instance.mainloop()
```

this is all my code, I want to resize the `MainFrame` on change level

Comment: pls, provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Imma say it is pretty horrible code, formatting wise

Comment: suggestion. when You want to change something: define it as function and in that function (this all about this case) destroy the previous widget and set a new one, and it should work

Comment: actually You are not even changing anything, I would say that You have not even tried, because it seems like random gibberish those functions that are supposed to set something, also how did You expect to change the table?

Comment: so the way U should do this for now at least. find a way/configuration which creates a table as You want (dunno like put buttons around or sth) then it should be easy from there. create a similar thing but bigger and so on, until You can at least by commenting out some code show tables on the screen because I don't see any there, and then put that into function

Comment: ok i understand i try to create the table first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so I made a sample from which You should have a rough idea of what to do:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button


root = Tk()
list_of_names = []


def grid(n):
    global list_of_names
    cnt = 0
    for row in range(n):
        for col in range(n):
            button = Button(root, text=f'{list_of_names[cnt]}', width=6, height=3)
            button.grid(row=row, column=col)
            cnt += 1


three = Button(root, text='3x3', command=lambda: grid(3))
three.grid()
four = Button(root, text='4x4', command=lambda: grid(4))
four.grid()
five = Button(root, text='5x5', command=lambda: grid(5))
five.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Sof that is great, if You have more questions just ask

Comment: I have a doubt, now to change the text of the buttons I have to identify them, but they are created in the loop, how can I change the text of the clicked button?

Comment: @Sof How do You want to identify them? can You put all the button names in a list?

Comment: i put the names in a list, but now i have tu check their text, to set it I have to make: buttonName.config(text=' '), but to get the text?

Comment: @Sof I edited the code a bit to give You the idea of how You can give each button a name from a list just make sure You have enough items in the list so that it does not cause errors